# Laravel how to store value based on checkbox checked

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to store 1 if checkbox is checked, otherwise 0. The form is

```
<x-checkbox name="visibility" id="visibility">{{ __('Make this visible') }}</x-checkbox>
```

In the controller, it is only storing the first value of the condition. This is always storing 0.

```
$request->visibility = 'checked' ? $package->visibility = 0 : $package->visibility = 1;
```

This is always storing 1.

```
$request->visibility = 'checked' ? $package->visibility = 1 : $package->visibility = 0;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $request->visibility = (int)$request->checked;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me :

```
$model->visibility = ($request->visibility) ? '1' : '0';
```